# RStudio 4.0.0 installation on Ubuntu 22.04 using the Makefile but the linker is unable to find libicu library

Tags: linker, icu, ubuntu-22.04, r-4.0.0

To make RStudio 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 using the given Makefile I installed libicu58.3 (icu4c) but the linker is unable to find libicu library. This is after installing JDK 1.8 and Apache Ant 1.10 to build libicu58.3.

I tried:

- To build libicu using ant
- To add the libicu to the linker search path
- To recompile R from scratch
- sudo apt update/upgrade